# Passing a parameter trough require-module to ES6 class in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I am learning to use ECMAScript6 -styled classes in NodeJS (7.7.3). I have used this kind of programming style:

```js
//app.js
var forecastHandler = require('./forecastHandler.js');

//forecastHandler.js
class ForecastHandler {
  constructor() {}
}

module.exports = new ForecastHandler()
```

It has worked well until now, because I have to pass parameters to module.

```js
//app.js
var forecastHandler = require('./forecastHandler.js')(3600);

//forecastHandler.js
class ForecastHandler {
  constructor(cacheUpdateDelay) {}
}

module.exports = new ForecastHandler(cacheUpdateDelay)
```

I got this error: ReferenceError: cacheUpdateDelay is not defined.
Can I pass the parameter to ForecastHandler-module using ES6 styled classes and creating an object at module.exports? If I only export the class and create the object in app.js, code works, but it's syntax is ugly.

```js
//app.js
var forecastHandlerClass = require('./forecastHandler.js');
var forecastHandler = new forecastHandlerClass(3600);

//forecastHandler.js
module.exports = ForecastHandler
```

EDIT: better examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module.exports = new ForecastHandler(cacheUpdateDelay)
```

The trouble with this code is that it initialises the object when the code is first run.

`require('./forecastHandler.js')` means "execute all the code in `forecastHandler.js` and give me the `exports` object. This means that the JS engine tries to run `new ForecastHandler(cacheUpdateDelay)` when there is no `cacheUpdateDelay` created.

The simple way to do this is the one you provide. Load the class, then try to make a new instance of it. If you *really* want to one-line it, you can do this in `app.js`:

```
var forecastHandler = new (require('./forecastHandler.js'))(3600);
```

There are various other ways you could do this. The simplest involve not exporting a class but a function.

For instance, you could do this in your module file:

```
module.exports = cacheUpdateDelay => new ForecastHandler(cacheUpdateDelay);
// OR
module.exports = function(cacheUpdateDelay) {
    return new ForecastHandler(cacheUpdateDelay);
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I'm too obsessed to one-liners.

Comment: Your parens are in the wrong place around the `require`. That will call `require` itself as a constructor, then return the module export in its place, then call the module export as a normal function without `new`.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Indeed, thank you for spotting that. This is of course the code that I intended. Although it is *not* code that I would advocate or use.